# Prevent user from entering white space during form input in asp.net model validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, whitespace

I have bee using model validation in asp.net MVC website.
I want to have a functionality to prevent user from entering whitespace in testbox and submit the form.

There are other validation attributes available, but i could not find any validation attribute that prevents user from entering only whitespace in the input textbox.

I could develop a custom attribute for this, but there is another method called regular expression validator which i think i could use easily to achieve this functionality. 
For example: We can set an attribute that has a regular expression for validating email. if User enters wrong email, immediately  a message is shown that email format is wrong.

I want use the same, but i don't know the regular expresison that validates a form input field if user enters only whitespace.

Please help me with this kind of regular expression?
Thanks,

Answer (score 13):

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^\s]+")]
public string Data { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Regex validation with this pattern:

```
^\S+$
```

This will allow only non-white-space.

### (Update)

If you want users to enter whitespace but only if there are non-whitespace in there:

```
\S+
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks you all for the reply. But above two regular expression doesn't work. I want to prevent user from entering only whitespace, they can however enter whitespace along with other words, for example a full name of a person "Steve Jobs". This name consist of a whitespace, this is valid.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression might work

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,-.@~!#$%&*<>?:;_='/()]+(\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9,-.@~!#$%&*<>?:;_='/()]+)*$
```

Comment: The character range `,-.` is cleverly equivalent to the character range `,-.`. I see what you did there.

Comment: Though this will still disallow leading whitespace.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.